# NuxtJS3 : Typescript TypeCheck not working

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm tying to enable typechecking in dev mode on Nuxtjs 3 but console is not showing any error.

[image: Node version]

The file that would show error :

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
  const toto:string = 1;
  const f:number = "XfffXX";
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ f }}
  </div>
</template>
```

The command nuxi typecheck is working :

[image: npx nuxi typecheck output]

On the browser side, no errors :

[image]

My nuxt.config.ts :

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    builder: 'webpack',
    typescript: {
        strict: true,
        typeCheck: true
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed `vue-tsc`, `vite-plugin-checker` as dev dependencies.

```
yarn add vue-tsc vite-plugin-checker --dev
```

Once that is done, add the following to your nuxt.config.ts:

```
import { checker } from 'vite-plugin-checker'

export default nuxtConfig({
  ...
  vite: {
    plugins: [
      checker({
        vueTsc: true,
      }),
    ]
  },
  ...
})
```

As of now, you should see the errors in the terminal with the `yarn dev` command. In a regular vue 3/vite project, you should also see the errors in the browser, but this doesn't [currently](https://github.com/fi3ework/vite-plugin-checker/issues/197) work with Nuxt 3. If you still want to show the errors in the browser, you can follow this [workaround](https://vite-plugin-checker.netlify.app/faq/integration.html#overlay-does-not-display-in-development-mode-1).

The guide says you also have to install `typescript` and `@types/node`, but I've tried this without them and it seems to work fine. It basically comes down to this:

1. Create a Vue component called VitePluginChecker.vue with the following content:

```
<script setup>
import('/@vite-plugin-checker-runtime-entry')
</script>
```

2. Use this component in your default layout (default.vue):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <VitePluginChecker />
  </div>
</template>
```

I hope this helps!